# React: setState hook closure runs twice

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm sure this is standard, well known behavior, but I don't know how to fix it. Whenever I use setState (in this case it's setTheirPokemon) the closure runs twice. To have it run 'once', I had to add extra variables at the top that check if it's already ran, and if it did, set it to that earlier state.

```
        /**
         * Fires when an opponent deletes one of their Pokemon.
         * Used to update the list of opponent Pokemon.
         * @param index The index of the Pokemon to delete.
         */
        socket.on('delete_pokemon', (index: number) => {
            let past: Pokemon[] | null = null

            setTheirPokemon(theirPokemon => {
                if (past === null) {

                    //stuff, isnt important
                    const newTheirPokemon = theirPokemon.filter(pokemon => {
                        return pokemon.index !== index
                    })
                    let newIndex = 0
                    newTheirPokemon.forEach(pokemon => {
                        pokemon.index = newIndex++
                    })

                    //so it won't rerun
                    past = newTheirPokemon
                    return newTheirPokemon
                } else { 
                    return past
                }
            })
        })
```

Is there a better way to do this, or have it run just once? Thanks.

Clarification:

The component is inside a useEffect with an empty dependancy array, so it should only run on mount, i think. The hooks also came from a seperate context file that I consumed, so the state doesnt belong to this component, if that matters.

Comment: Did you remove the React.StrictMode?

Comment: `let x = 1` <- this is how you know you're hacking things.

Comment: Show the rest of the code - are you attaching this listener "inside" a component - i.e. are you creating this listener every time the component is rendered (so sometimes you have two [or multiple] listeners going instead of one?)

Comment: It is in a useEffect with an empty dependancy array, so it shouldnt run again on rerender

Comment: Also, how do I check if strict mode is still there? I'm using CRA, and in the index.tsx page, it is surrounded by <React.StrictMode>

Comment: Are you using the React.strictMode ?

Comment: I believe so, if the comment two above yours means it is

Comment: Do you have linting? I do not see your complete code,  but something says me,  there is an issue in exhaustive deps lint rule, maybe the dependency should include `socket`? https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/14920

Comment: And are you removing the socket listener on unmount? ```useEffect(()=> { setSocketListener(); return ()=> removeSocketListener() }, [someSocketDependency])```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"It's an intentional feature of the StrictMode. This only happens in development, and helps find accidental side effects put into the render phase. We only do this for components with Hooks because those are more likely to accidentally have side effects in the wrong place."
https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/15074